# Connecting git to github on windows 7 without bash

Tags: git, powershell, windows-7, ssh, github

I'm setting up git on my new Windows 7 machine and I'm hitting a roadblock when it comes to getting github to acknowledge my ssh key. I am doing things a little different from the standard script in that I would rather not use cygwin and prefer to use my powershell prompt.  The following is what I did:

1. I installed msysgit (portable).
2. I went to C:\program files\git\bin and used ssh-keygen to generate a public/private ssh keypair which I put in c:\Temp
3. I then created a directory named .ssh\ in c:\Users\myusername\ (on windows 7)
4. I moved both the files generated by the ssh-keygen (id_rsa and id_rsa.pub) into the .ssh directory
5. I went to my account on github, created a new public key, copy-pasted the contents of id_rsa.pub into it and saved
6. I now go to my powershell prompt, set-alias git 'C:\program files\git\bin\git.exe'
7. I try to now do a clone git@github.com:togakangaroo/ps-profile.git which rejects my authentication:

   Permission denied (publickey). 
   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Past experience says that this means git is not recognizing my key.  What steps am I missing?

I have a feeling that I need to somehow configure git so that it knows where my ssh keys are (though it would seem it should look there automatically) but I don't know how to do that.

Another possible clue is that when I try to run git config --global user.name "George Mauer"
I get an error

```
fatal: $HOME not set
```

I did however set up a HOME environment user variable with the value %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command you're looking for is:
 `ssh-add C:\path\to\key`

First, you may want to find out where ssh is currently looking for your keys, by running `ssh -v git@github.com`

Comment: are ssh and ssh-add utilities that are in the git\bin directory?  I'm not using bash here

Comment: Sorry, spoke too soon, I see that they are there.  I get this when I run ssh:  http://pastebin.com/G6FPN9As  What in the world does it all mean?

Comment: It looks like ssh is looking for the keys in C:\program files\git\bin\.ssh.  The simplest solution would be to copy the keys to that directory.  But if you like where they are, then run ssh-add c:\Users\myusername\.ssh .

Comment: I think I'd prefer to keep it well organized - but running ssh-add gives me "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Comment: Try setting the path to include the portable installation's cmd directory: `set path=c:\yourpath\portablegit\cmd;%path%`.  See if that temporarily helps ssh-add or git-config work.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. I accidently added the wrong directory to the path.

After I changed that from `*\Git\bin\` to `*\Git\cmd\` everything worked.

`git.cmd` sets up the environment variables.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Now `git push origin develop` correctly asks me for the passphrase of my SSH key. The file inside `*\Git\cmd` is named `git.exe` for me as well, by the way. I hadn’t set the path myself, so I guess a chose the wrong option when installing msysgit – at some point he asks you from where you want to use it, `cmd`, `git bash`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

My solution to the

> "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

error on Windows 7 was to first run `ssh -v git@github.com` in the git Bash console to find out what sort of public key file Github was looking for. The filename I saw was `id_rsa`.

Then, I viewed the `c:\users\username\.ssh` folder in Windows Explorer and noticed that while there was no `id_rsa` file, there was `github_rsa` and `github_rsa.pub`.

Copying these files in the `c:\users\username\.ssh` folder and renaming the copies to `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` respectively solved the issue for me.

I was then able to push local commits to the repository on Github.

Answer (score 7):

I have same problem, It's fixed by putting your `id_rsa`* file at `C:\Program Files\Git\.ssh` folder

Comment: Tried everything else but in vain. Thought I will try out this too.. It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on Windows 7.   Once I addressed the missing HOME environment variable by pointing HOME to c/Users/wherever the problem was fixed.

More here: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=482

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with PowerShell for ~3 hours.

Simply set your HOME variable to be

```
C:\Users\Your Username
```

and restart PowerShell. Then ensure all your keys and all match.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, but it was caused by Internet Explorer 8.0.7600 having a JavaScript error when trying to perform the "add key" button functionality on my GitHub login "Account Settings"  page "SSH Public Keys".  This meant that the add key failed, and the key was not listed on the page of public keys above the link "Add another key". I switched to Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's completely necessary, I would recommend not using the portable mysysgit. This worked almost out-of-the-box for me using the normal mysysgit installed.

However, I did recently set this up on a new Windows machine and ran into a similar issue. This was fixed by converting my plink SSH key into an OpenSSH-compatible key, and moving this into my personal .ssh folder. After that, it worked a charm!

If interested, [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux)