# Netbeans, git, reject hostKey?

Tags: git, netbeans, ssh, clone

I'm currently trying to get Netbeans with the Git plugin working.
If I want to clone my git repository from within Netbeans I get the error message:
`reject hostKey: [repository url]`
and the cloning aborts.

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: How do you access your repo? Where is the repo? Github? More context would provide better answers...

Comment: It's on sourceforge. Accessed with ssh://[url]. The read-only rep from SF (git://[url]) works without problems, but I need write access to my project of course. Netbeans 7.0.1 + Netbeans own git plugin. Windows 7 + Java 7, both 64 bit. That's all I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check what user is running NetBeans, and then make sure your ssh private and public keys (`id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`) are in the associated `HOME/.ssh` of that user.

Note that on Windows, `HOME` isn't defined by default, so you need to set that variable before running Netbeans.

Comment: Where do I define these variables on Windows? Are they environment variables from Windows? Or some config options from Netbeans? In c:\users\[name] I have a "ssh" folder, but without the invisible dot (".ssh"), it contains a known hosts file.

Comment: @blubberbernd: there is only one Windows environment variable to define: `HOME`. And you need a .ssh in it with your public and private keys. More on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328599/connecting-git-to-github-on-windows-7-without-bash and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112781/cannot-get-git-extensions-to-push-something-to-github-ssh-problems-solved/4112933#4112933 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612923/error-in-setting-up-ssh-keys-with-windows-powershell/6612996#6612996