# 'Auth cancel' error when trying to checkout a github repository using SSH via NetBeans

Tags: macos, github, ssh, netbeans7.0

I've set up github properly with SSH keys, and the following command succeeds, as per their setup docs:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

However, when using the git plugin in Netbeans 7.0 to clone a repo (one that I have forked), I try to enter the git@github:myusername/forkedrepo address and immediately get an error saying 'Auth cancel' when I click 'next'.

It seems to not be using the SSH key at all, as there's no mention in the message log of key authentication.

What could cause this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: A bit like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986617/netbeans-git-reject-hostkey, but on OsX, $HOME should be defined.

Comment: id_rsa and id_rsa.pub are both in the /Users/currentuser/.ssh directory. I've also tried creating /Users/githubusername/.ssh and copying them into there, but with no luck.

Comment: echo $HOME at the terminal gives /Users/currentuser, which is presumably the same user as Netbeans is running as.